# Checking multiple conditions for a "password"

Tags: python

I'm trying to write code that can check if an input contains;

- At least 8 letters, whereas at least 1 of those is a number (0-9)
- Contains an upper and lower case character

I keep getting stuck in a "inputs password, returns true, and input password again, exit" single loop..

Fairly new at programming, doing my first semester atm so all help would be appreciated!

This is my program so far

```
def is_valid():
    valid = 0
    password = input("Password: ")
    for ele in password:
        if ele.isupper and ele.islower and ele.isdigit and len(password) > 7:
            return "True"
        else:
            return "False"
    print(is_valid())
is_valid()
```

I tried moving the print inside the function, as I think it is intended, by then It won't print..

Comment: "This is my program so far" is blank.

Comment: Why are you calling `is_valid` from inside `is_valid`?

Comment: The `return` statement causes the function to exit immediately.  So your function always exits after processing just one letter in the password.

Comment: Doing old exams sets right now - And it was just what they proposed we could call such a function

Comment: `isupper`, `islower`, `isdigit` are methods on the `str` class and need to be followed with `()` in order to actually call the function, e.g. `ele.isupper()` will actually test if the character is upper case.

Comment: Oh, if I move the print outside of the function I get stuck in the "input, print, input" loopy thing tho..

Comment: You are also currently checking if _each_ character in the password is all of these conditions, which wouldn't ever work (something can't be upper and lowercase at the same time). You'll want to keep track of whether you've seen an uppercase letter, a digit, etc. and if you've seen all the necessary requirements after looping through all characters, you can return True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. But first I will clarify some mistakes.

First, when you write `ele.isupper` you are not calling the function, for that you must put the parenthesis: `ele.isupper()`.

Secondly, your loop is looping through each letter of the password and in the case of solving the previous bug you would find that the condition would never be fulfilled since a character cannot be all things at the same time.

I leave you an example of how you can solve these problems, as I said, there are many ways to do it but I present you one that is not complex and uses the basics. Also, if the password is incorrect, ask for it again on the screen.

```
def is_valid():

    valid = [0, 0, 0]

    password = input("Password: ")

    for ele in password:
        
        if len(password) < 8:
            break
        elif ele.isupper() and valid[0] == 0:
            valid[0] = 1
        elif ele.islower() and valid[1] == 0:
            valid[1] = 1
        elif ele.isdigit() and valid[2] == 0:
            valid[2] = 1
        
    if sum(valid) < 3:
        print('False')
        is_valid()
    else:
        print('True')
        
is_valid()
```

Output:

```
Password: hello
False
Password: Hello
False
Password: Hello World
False
Password: Hello World 1 
True
```

The code first checks if the length is correct, if it is not, it does not make any further checks.

If this condition is met it continues and as conditions are met, one of the variables in the `valid` list is incremented. You can do this with a number instead of a list, but if you want to specify what has gone wrong you can access each value in the list to check it or say that n conditions have failed, for example:

```
if valid[1] == 0:
    print('There must be at least one lower character').
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for ele in password:
    if ele.isupper and ele.islower and ele.isdigit and len(password) > 7:
        return "True"
    else:
        return "False"
```

This code has several problems.

First, you're *referring* to the `ele.isupper` function, but because you don't have parentheses `()`, you're not *calling* the function.  So the code is basically asking "Does `ele.isupper` exist"?  Well yes, it is a function, and it exists, so the `if` condition is true.

Use `ele.isupper()` instead of `ele.isupper`.

Second, even if you fix that problem (and also the same problem for `ele.islower` and `ele.isdigit`), there's no way that one letter will be uppercase AND lowercase AND a digit.

Third, the `return` statement makes the function exit immediately, so your loop will only look at the first letter.  Instead of doing that, you want to loop over *all* the letters, and move the `return` statement to *after* the loop.

I think you were actually looking for code like this:

```
uc = 0
lc = 0
digits = 0

for ele in password:
    if ele.isupper():
        uc += 1
    elif ele.islower():
        lc += 1
    elif ele.isdigit():
        digits += 1

if uc > 1 and lc > 1 and digits > 1 and len(password) > 7:
    return "True"
else:
    return "False"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, super helpful and informative!

Answer (score 1):

You're going element-wise in a loop on your password, rather than considering the whole thing together. You want something like:

```
def is_valid():
    password = input("Password: ")
    if not any(el.isupper() for el in password):
        return False

    if not any(el.islower() for el in password):
        return False

    if not any(el.isdigit() for el in password):
        return False

    if len(password) < 8:
        return False

    return True

is_valid()
```

Comment: @PirateNinjas Did you test this?

Comment: @JonasDanielsen Try it with a password of 8 characters all lowercase

Comment: Yes it worked as it should only returning 1 statement either True or False - The other examples returns multiple statements as in 2 false and 1 true if not all conditions are met - It does however ask me to type in a new password after returning, and I'm not sure, but I don't think it's supposed to?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems in your code.

1. Reaching return statement exits the loop and the function itself, returning the value. So you are just checking first letter and the immediately finish the loop.
2. `valid = 0` seems to be never used.
3. Last instruction if your function `print(is_valid())` would also have no effect.

One possible straightforward solution to your problem would be to set a number of different flags for things you want to check, ant then once you find them, set te proper value for the flags. Like this:

```py
def is_valid():
    password = input("Password: ")
    has_upper = False
    has_digit = False
    has_lower = False
    has_good_length = False
    for ele in password:
        if ele.isupper():
            has_upper = True
        if ele.islower():
            has_lower = True
        if ele.isdigit():
            has_digit = True
    if len(password) > 7:
        has_good_length = True
    if has_upper and has_lower and has_digit and has_good_length:
        return True
    return False


print(is_valid())
```

Comment: (The value = 0 is from another attempt yes aha, just forgot to delete!)

Answer (score 1):

You should also check for characters that are neither letters nor digits (according to the rules stated in the question) - e.g., punctuation.

How about using a bit mask?

```
def is_valid(pwd):
    state = 0
    if len(pwd) >= 8:
        for c in pwd:
            if c.isdigit():
                state |= 1
            elif c.islower():
                state |= 2
            elif c.isupper():
                state |= 4
            else:
                state |= 8
    return state == 7


password = input('Password: ')
print(is_valid(password))
```

Comment: Actually hadn't though about that, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

for ele in password will iterate through the characters in the user's input.

your if statement doesnt make sense.  ele.isupper and ele.islower will never be true at the same time.

if statement needs work.  make booleans for each condition you want to validate and set them to true individually is you see the required elements.

Comment: Thank you, super helpful and informative!

Comment: @Pete - ele.isupper is "truthy" and so, in fact, is always True in a conditional context. However, ele.isupper() will result in either True or False depending on what the variable *ele* refers to

Comment: Yes that is also a problem.